# Magento Admin Dashboard modification

Tags: magento-1.5, magento

A client noticed that the Admin Dashboard calculations in her system aren’t matching up with the Order report, in that what’s being called ‘Revenue’ is actually displaying profit as demonstrated in the attached shots.

[image: order report]

What I want to do is modify the Dashboard page to add a 5th element which would be the actual Revenue and not Profit.

I’ve gotten as far adding the element to the page.

[image: admin dashboard]

To do this I copied Totals.php from /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/ to /app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/.  This is the code that I modified:

```
    $totals = $collection->getFirstItem();
    $this->addTotal($this->__('Revenue'), $totals->getProfit());
    $this->addTotal($this->__('Profit'), $totals->getRevenue());
    $this->addTotal($this->__('Tax'), $totals->getTax());
    $this->addTotal($this->__('Shipping'), $totals->getShipping());
    $this->addTotal($this->__('Quantity'), $totals->getQuantity()*1, true);
```

I just can’t seem to find the actual variable that I need to call.  Does anyone have any idea how I can locate it or what it might be? I've tried Sales, SalesTotal, Invoiced and they all return zero.

It’s the value that’s being displayed as Sales Total in the 1st image.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

The variable that I'm looking for isn't loading in this file.  I've hunted down Grid.php in /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Report/Sales/Sales/ which is what's drawing the table in the 1st image.

I've tried inserting

```
Mage::log($totals->debug());
```

in various places but it causes an error in each instance.

Here's a snippet of code from Grid.php, either of these values would work for me..

```
$this->addColumn('total_income_amount', array(
        'header'        => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Sales Total'),
        'type'          => 'currency',
        'currency_code' => $currencyCode,
        'index'         => 'total_income_amount',
        'total'         => 'sum',
        'sortable'      => false
    ));

    $this->addColumn('total_revenue_amount', array(
        'header'        => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Revenue'),
        'type'          => 'currency',
        'currency_code' => $currencyCode,
        'index'         => 'total_revenue_amount',
        'total'         => 'sum',
        'sortable'      => false,
        'visibility_filter' => array('show_actual_columns')
    ));
```

Comment: Bumping for Monday morning...Anyone? :)

Comment: Comments don't bump a question any higher. Also I added a `magento` tag since more people are likely to see that.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on logging in *System > Configuration > Developer* and then next to your overridden code put:

```
Mage::log($totals->debug());
```

Watch the "var/log/system.log" file as you refresh the page and it will dump `$totals` for you. Find the index of the value you want and convert it to camel case, for example if you see `sales_total` then you can use `$totals->getSalesTotal()` (which you have already tried, this is only an example).

Remember to turn off logging when the site goes live.

Comment: There's no other variable being pulled in on this page. I'm updating my question with some additional info